# When using SQL (Teradata) to fuzzy search multiple words, in the result, how can you list which word is matched?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, tabular, fuzzy-search

I want to use like to query some records like:

```
select table1.survey_txt where table1.survey_txt like any (
'%aaaa%',
'%bbbb%',
'%cccc%',
'%dddd%',
'%eeee%',
'%[^a-z0-9]ffff[^a-z0-9]%'
)
```

The result will be like:

**survey_txt**

heheaaaahehe

kekeaaaakeke

uueabbbbk

jioewccccfjo

esjoffffownr

---

So how can I make the result like:

**survey_txt..........matched_word**

heheaaaahehe........aaaa

kekeaaaakeke.........aaaa

uueabbbbk...............bbbb

jioewccccfjo..............cccc

esjoffffownr..................ffff

---

This is a table but I don't know how to make a table here so I just used "....." to make it look like table.

Answer (score 3):

Use REGEXP_SUBSTR instead of LIKE:

```
SELECT survey_txt,
   RegExp_Substr(survey_txt, '(aaaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd|eeee|[^a-z0-9]ffff[^a-z0-9])') AS matched_word
FROM surveys
WHERE matched_word IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works very well. Do you by any chance know how can I do the same thing in Python pandas DataFrame? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try building a table with the search words and like strings, then inner joining. Since you are using Teradata something like this example should work:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE searchwordslist
  (searchword VARCHAR(32)
  , likestring VARCHAR(32))
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;
INSERT INTO searchwordslist VALUES('aaaa', '%aaaa%');
INSERT INTO searchwordslist VALUES('bbbb', '%bbbb%'); 
--and so on for all the words
```

So now our `searchwordlist` table looks like:

```
searchword  likestring
bbbb        %bbbb%
aaaa        %aaaa%
```

Then your query is:

```
SELECT a.survey_txt 
  , b.searchword
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN searchwordslist b
  ON a.survey_txt LIKE b.likestring
;
```

Giving your desired result:

```
survey_txt      searchword
heheaaaahehehe  aaaa
kekebbbbkeke    bbbb
```

Comment: There's no need for two columns in your `searchwordlist` table, simply use a single `searchword` and then compare using `LIKE '%'|| b.likestring || '%'`, it's easier to maintain.